# How to create shortcodes with function inside function in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, shortcode

In my theme function.php i am trying to add shortcodes for  myHeader, myFooter etc .

Inside **myHeader()**, **myFooter()** function i added another function like **fn_1()**, **fn_2()**, **fn3_()** etc these function would be change weekly or monthly basis.

Is it possible to call a shortcode as written below

```
function myHeader(){
    fn_1();
    //fn_2();
}

function myFooter(){
    fn_2();
//  fn_3();

}
add_shortcode('myFooter', 'myHeader');
add_shortcode('myFooter', 'myFooter');


function fn_1(){
    return 'something for 1';
}

function fn_2(){
    return 'something for 2';
}

function fn_3(){
    return 'something for 3';
}
```

In my post i call my shortcode as [myHeader] and [myFooter]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, you just need to return something inside your shortcode methods. Shortcode functions also require some variables, though they don't actually have to be used.

eg.

```
function myHeader($atts, $content = null){
   $temp = fn_1();
   return $temp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it is compulsory to add the parameter ($atts, $content = null), because I am not passing any parameters to myHeader(), myFooter function, it just return some string

Comment: From my experience, it's better to add the parameters.

Comment: thanks will try it, and if this work will mark as an answer

Answer (score 0):

$atts is required to create shortcode if you are passing $atts or not.